# How to fetch in JavaScript URLs which respond GZIP headers

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am looking how to fetch in JavaScript URLs which respond GZIP headers then parse the content to JSON.
I have tried :

```js
function fetchJson(url, callback = null, callbackError = null, unzip = false) {
    fetch(url) 
    .then(r => { 
        if (unzip) r = atob(r);
        return r.json();
    })  
    .then(r => {
        if (callback !== null) callback(r);
    })  
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        if (callbackError !== null) callbackError();
    }); 
};
```

But I get this error :

```
DOMException: String contains an invalid character
```

Comment: The host browser should be handling GZip compression for you... something's not right. Are you running this code inside a browser or inside a different host process?

Comment: The JavaScript code is running from the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to manually decompress responses, and `atob` would not be the way to do it. If your `unzip` parameter was truthy, that likely would've caused the error. Also if this function should only ever fetch JSON, it might be handy to set that explicitly as a header.

```
function fetchJson(url, callback = null, callbackError = null) {
  fetch(url, { headers: { 'accept': 'application/json; charset=utf8;' } }) 
    .then(r => return r.json())  
    .then(r => {
      if (callback !== null) callback(r);
    })  
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      if (callbackError !== null) callbackError();
    }); 
};
```

Comment: I have tried your solution, and I get the following error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data" maybe there is an error on the backend, isn't it? 
Moreover, I have checked the header the server returns:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
 DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
 GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
 *
Content-Encoding
 gzip
Content-Type
 application/octet-stream

Comment: Sounds like the server may not actually be returning JSON then. If you change `r.json()` to `r.text()` and console.log that out in another `.then`, does it appear to be JSON?

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It looks like JSON but some value are broken, I think it comes from python, e. g. 'closed_date': None,
              'creation_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 5, 10, 0),
              'is_disabled': False,

Comment: Ahh, that would be it. Looks like the API you're hitting is stringifying a dict rather than sending it as json.

Comment: Thank you for your precious help! I will contact the guy who has developed this API. :)